# .NET Build Error After Converting to VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

After converting a VS 2005 project to VS 2008 I started encountering the following error:

Task failed because "LC.exe" was not found, or the correct Microsoft Windows SDK is not installed. The task is looking for "LC.exe" in the "bin" subdirectory beneath the location specified in the InstallationFolder value of the registry key 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A. 
You may be able to solve the problem by doing one of the following:
1) Install the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5.
2) Install Visual Studio 2008.  3) Manually set the above registry key to the correct location.  4) Pass the correct location into the "ToolPath" parameter of the task.

What needs to be done in order to resolve this problem and why did is start happening?  This is a fresh install of VS 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some analysis on the web I found that the problem was related to installing SP1 of VS 2008, which I had previously done.  Actually my install steps for VS 2008 were as follows:

1. Install VS 2008
2. Install TFS 2008 Client
3. Install VS 2008 SP1
4. Restart Computer

In order to fix the issue I attempted to add a new entry in the registry for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs.NETFramework\v3.5\InstallationFolder as suggested by the following article.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/93fe03a0-117c-406e-b0ea-c2e2227e1835

That step did not resolve the problem though.  In order to resolve the problem I had to install the Windows Server 2008 SDK and .NET 3.5 which is provided at:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E6E1C3DF-A74F-4207-8586-711EBE331CDC&displaylang=en&displaylang=en

After I installed the SDK I started VS 2008 back up and was able to build my projects without encountering the same error.

I'm not sure if SP1 was actually the culprit or not, but the fix seems simple enough.